# How use shared services with controllers that use no shared services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-module

Assume there is a module with only one factory (the shared service).

```
angular.module('sharedService', [])
    .factory('sharedSrv', sharedService)

function sharedService() {
  var number;

  return {
    getNum: getNumber
  };

  function getNumber() {
    return number;
  }

  function setNumber(i) {
    number = i;
  }
}
```

I saw we can inject shared services by passing a dependency into module

```
angular.module('app', ['sharedService'])
.controller('theCtrl', function(sharedSrv) {
  var self = this;

  self.setSharedNumber = sharedSrv.setNumber;
}
```

However, How inject a shared service if controller use services from his own module?

```
angular.module('app', ['sharedService'])
.controller('theCtrl', theCtrlFun)
.service('theSrv', theSrvFun)

theCtrlFun.$inject = ['theSrv']

function theCtrlFun(localSrv) {
 // How call sharedService ? 
}

function theSrvFun() {
  // Some fantastic features.
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be injecting service module as variable, you need to pass the name of module as `string`

```
angular.module('app', [sharedService])
.controller('theCtrl', function(sharedSrv) {
```

should be

```
angular.module('app', ['sharedService'])
.controller('theCtrl', function(sharedSrv) {
```

OR you could follow Inline Array annotation of DI

```
angular.module('app', ['sharedService'])
.controller('theCtrl', ["sharedSrv",  function(sharedSrv) {
    //code here
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your correction. But in your last block, how "sharedSrv" will be recognize if this service is in another module of app ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `sharedService` from statement `angular.module('app', [sharedService])` as your shared services are not part of this module.

You need to inject  the `theSrv` and not `theSrvFun` in the statement `theCtrlFun.$inject = ['theSrv']`

In the `theCtrlFun` function just call the method of this service.
e.g `someMethod` is defined on the  `theSrv` service,you need to call like this

```
theSrv.someMethod();
```

e.g.

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('theCtrl', theCtrlFun)
    .service('theSrv', theSrvFun)

theCtrlFun.$inject = ['theSrv']

function theCtrlFun(localSrv) {
    theSrv.someMethod(); // calll in this way
}

function theSrvFun() {
    // Some fantastic features.
}
```

Its better to define DI using [Array Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('theCtrl', ['theSrv', function(theSrv) {

        theSrv.callMe();

    }])
    .service('theSrv', function() {

        this.callMe = funtion() {


        }

    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I made effectively many mistakes in syntax.
But I want to use sharedService AND TheSrv in the same controllerm simultaneously. (The Srv will contains tools only for theCtrl, but sharedService will be used by other modules).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('theCtrl', theCtrlFun)
.service('theSrv', theSrvFun)

theCtrlFun.$inject = ['theSrv']

function theCtrlFun(localSrv) {
 // How call sharedService ? 
 console.log(localSrv)
}

function theSrvFun() {
  // Some fantastic features.
}
```

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/lSosJbYfG6tuF4pCXYqR?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, I made mistakes.

But if I want to use theSrv AND sharedService in the same controller, how can I do ?

Comment: to use the service from another module, you need to inject that module to your module and then inject service from that module to your controller